# Pandas library returning nan

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I'm trying to filtrate some data creating a subset on python using pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("movies.csv")
PG_13 = data[data.mpaa == "PG-13"]

print(PG_13.year.min())
```

It works but it always returns "nan" instead of the year I'm looking for on the subset.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked to see if `PG_13.year` has anything except `nan` values in it? (eg - does `PG_13.year.count()` return non-zero?

Comment: One way to check what JonClements is suggested is `print(PG_13['year'].unique())`

Comment: Yes, I have checked the file and everything inside it on that column are integers but I just checked the count and it's returning 0 so it's not getting my condition for the subset , i have no idea why...

Comment: So is `len(PG_13) == 0` then? If so - you might want to do `data.mpaa.value_counts()` to see what your actual values are in column... you might want "PG13" or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check your values in `PG_13.year`, like `PG_13.year.value_counts()`. If u had there some missings(ur *nan values*), u can remove them or fill by [`fillna(0)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) function.

Comment: `PG_13.year.value_counts()` wont give the `nan` count.  To get that you have to use `PG_13.year.value_counts(dropna=False)`

Comment: It says it has no values in it when I count them. I checked and the person who created the file included a extra space on the " PG-13" != "PG-13" so the subset was empty.
Thanks for letting me know to see if there was something inside the data set